# How to parentchildstring in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I have a question about SQL Server. How to convert json format using multiple tables?

emp_addr:

```
empid | city | state | country | doj
------+------+-------+---------+-----------
1     | bang | KA    | Ind     | 2018-08-03
2     | chen | Tn    | Ind     | 2018-02-04
```

emp_addressline:

```
empdid | addressline | addresscode 
-------+-------------+-------------
1      | street1     | street1
1      | street2     | taluka
1      | street2     | district
2      | street1     | street1
2      | street3     | district
```

emp_proof:

```
empdid | prooftype
-------+-----------
1      | aadhar
2      | voterid
```

Based on above data, I want output like this:

```
empid | city  | doj        | empjson
1     | bang  | 2018-08-03 | {"city":"bang","state":"ka","country":"ind","addreslineinfo":{"street1":"stree1","taluka":"street2","district":street2"},"prooftype":"aadhar"}
1     | chen  | 2018-02-04 | {"city":"bang","state":"ka","country":"ind","addreslineinfo":{"street1":"stree1","district":street3"},"prooftype":"voterid"}
```

I tried with this SQL query:

```
select  
    empid, city, doj,
    (select city, state, country, addresscode, addressline, prooftype 
     for json path, include_null_values, without_array_wrapper) empjson 
from 
    emp_addr a 
inner join 
    emp_addressline b on a.empid = b.empid 
inner join 
    emp_proof c on a.empid = c.empid
```

This query is not returning the expected result. Could you please tell me how to write a query to achieve this task in SQL Server?